# Decrease height of mat-button-toggle to match buttons

Tags: angular-material

I got an Angular Flex-Layout row which contains some buttons and a `mat-button-toggle-group`. Unfortunately, the `mat-button-toggle-group` is somewhat bigger than the buttons and I would like to have them all on the same height / line-height.

This is hot it looks currently:
[image: Screenshot]

Tried to meddle with the css classes of `mat-button-toggle-group` and others, but only got to so far as to reduce the button height while the content stayed the same.

```html
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between end">
    <div>
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between end">
          <div class="control-buttons">
            <button
              mat-stroked-button
            >
              <i class="material-icons">skip_previous</i>
            </button>    
            ( more buttons )
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between end">
            <mat-button-toggle-group multiple>
                  <mat-button-toggle
                    value="random"
                  >
                    <i class="material-icons">
                      shuffle
                    </i>
                    <span class="only-on-big-screen">
                      random
                    </span>                
                  </mat-button-toggle>    
                  ( more buttons )
              </mat-button-toggle-group>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 25):

Another workaround would be to do this:

```
.mat-button-toggle-group {
  height: 32px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: perfectly working Thanks (y)

Comment: Best answer.  Using .mat-button-toggle-label-content  is incorrect as the height of the mat-button-toggle is still fatter than mat-button.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the height by adding custom styles. You have to change the `line-height` of the class `mat-button-toggle-label-content`.

```
.mat-button-toggle-label-content {
    line-height: 32px !important;  <-- set you height here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was reducing the line-height of the content and adjusting height of the buttons in a global style file.

```
.mat-button-toggle-button {
 height: 2rem; // the modified height that I wanted.
}

.mat-button-toggle-appearance-standard .mat-button-toggle-label-content {
  line-height: 1rem; // default value is 48px. I wanted the height to be 2rem, but had to adjust this line-height to 1rem so that the icons were vertically centered.
 }
```